# [Solved] Turtlebot simulation. Depth image duplicated

Tags: ros, simulation, turtlebot, camera, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I'm working with the turtlebot simulator using ROS Fuerte. I have a problem with visualising (and subsequently using) the depth image. The depth image I receive looks like this, http://postimg.org/image/q8lsehaon/. As you can see, the depth image looks correct, but is duplicated six times.

I've used my own conversion method (which produced the posted image) and rviz to display in the image. Both produce the same result, albeit rviz makes the depth image flicker. Has anyone has any experience with this or has an idea of how to solve this?

The depth image is published on /depth/image_raw. One oddity is that the topic /depth/camera_info does not produce any messages.

```
rostopic echo /depth/camera_info 
WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

The coloured images are published via the topic /camera/image_raw and /camera/camera_info publishes the camera info. Both work correctly and display the correct image.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Kind regards,

Bram

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62391/%5Bsolved%5D-turtlebot-simulation.-depth-image-duplicated./) by [Bram Ridder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4844/bram-ridder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you are facing the same issue as here: http://answers.ros.org/question/45659/openni-gazebo-plugin-stepsize-for-depth-images-bug/

IIRC, the patch linked at the end of the ticket was not backported to Fuerte. You can try building gazebo from source after applying the patch.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bram Ridder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4844/bram-ridder/) on 2013-05-09**:
Thank you very much! That was it :).